# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in laravel 7

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am editing the next error while printing a model content on my blade.php view:

And this is how i'm trying to use it on my view:

blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="color">انتخاب رنگ</label>
    @if(!$product->colors)
        <div id="showColors"> </div>
    @else
        <div class="row no-gutters mb-1">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="color_name" class="ml-1">نام رنگ:</label>
                <input type="text" id="color_name" name="color_name[]" class="form-control w-auto d-inline" value="{{ old('color_name') }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="color_code" class="ml-1">کد رنگ:</label>
                <input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code[]" class="form-control w-75 d-inline jscolor" value="{{ old('color_code') }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <a onclick="addColor()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> افزودن</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        showColors();
        function showColors() {
            let html = '@foreach($product->colors as $color)\n'+
            '<div class="row no-gutters mb-1">\n'+
            '<div class="col-md-3">\n'+
            '<label for="color_name" class="ml-1">نام رنگ:</label>\n'+
            '<input type="text" id="color_name" name="color_name[]" class="form-control w-auto d-inline" value="{{ $color->color_name }}">\n'+
            '</div>\n'+
            '<div class="col-md-3">\n'+
            '<label for="color_code" class="ml-1">کد رنگ:</label>\n'+
            '<input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code[]" class="form-control w-75 d-inline jscolor" value="{{ $color->color_code }}">\n'+
            '</div>\n'+
            '<div class="col-md-1">\n'+
            '<a onclick="addColor()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>\n'+
            '<a onclick="deleteColor(this)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>\n'+
            '</div>\n'+
            '</div>\n'+
            '@endforeach';
            $('#showColors').append(html);
        }
        addColor = function(){
            let html = '<div class="row no-gutters mb-1">\n'+
                '<div class="col-md-3">\n'+
                '<label for="color_name" class="ml-1">نام رنگ:</label>\n'+
                '<input type="text" id="color_name" name="color_name[]" class="form-control w-auto d-inline">\n'+
                '</div>\n'+
                '<div class="col-md-3">\n'+
                '<label for="color_code" class="ml-1">کد رنگ:</label>\n'+
                '<input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code[]" class="form-control w-75 d-inline jscolor">\n'+
                '</div>\n'+
                '<div class="col-md-1">\n'+
                '<a onclick="addColor()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>\n'+
                '<a onclick="deleteColor(this)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>\n'+
                '</div>\n'+
                '</div>';
            $('#showColors').append(html);
            // new jscolor($('.jscolor').last()[0]);
        };
        deleteColor = function(obj) {
            $(obj).parent().parent().remove();
        };
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function update(ProductRequest $request, Product $product)
{
    $data = [
        'title' => $request->title,
        'latin' => $request->latin,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'discount' => $request->discount,
        'coupon' => $request->coupon,
        'product_number' => $request->product_number,
        'order_product' => 0,
        'status' => $request->has('status'),
        'special' => $request->has('special'),
        'publish' => $request->has('publish'),
        'body' => $request->body,
        'keywords' => $request->keywords,
        'descriptions' => $request->descriptions,
    ];
    $product->update($data);
    $product->categories()->sync($request->category_id);
    $colorCodes = $request->color_code;
    $colorNames = $request->color_name;
    foreach ($colorCodes as $key => $color_code) {
        if (!empty($color_code) && !empty($colorNames[$key])) {
            $color = new Color;
            $color->product_id = $product->id;
            $color->color_code = $request->color_code;
            $color->color_name = $request->color_name;
            $color->save();
        }
    }
    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

But when the contents of the data then Submit the following error message appears:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

**I'm on the edit page. When I click save. it has error.**

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: name="color_name" and name="color_code" - delete [].

Comment: My form is like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkcAw.png

Comment: To expand on @Maksim comment, by adding `[]` to the input name you are creating an array.  When you output that array in the blade view you're getting an error because  `htmlspecialchars()` expects a string (which Laravel uses under the hood when you use `{{ $color->color_code }}`).

Comment: Okay, what is the solution?

Comment: Than you show not full code. You have foreach, right? Add index from this cycle to form name and old() value

Comment: What code can I show you?

Comment: I updated my post.