# Validate inputs with the same name recieved htmlspecialchars() error raised

Tags: php, html, laravel, validation

i have a form with multiple inputs with the same name as the following:

```
.... OTHER INPUTS BIENG VALIDATED ....
<input type="text" id="firstname_conjoint_associe" placeholder="" class="form-control " value="" name="firstname_conjoint_associe[]">
<input type="text" id="lastname_conjoint_associe" placeholder="" class="form-control " value="" name="lastname_conjoint_associe[]">
<input type="text" id="email_conjoint_associe" placeholder="" class="form-control " value="" name="email_conjoint_associe[]">
<input type="text" id="firstname_conjoint_associe" placeholder="" class="form-control " value="" name="firstname_conjoint_associe[]">
<input type="text" id="latname_conjoint_associe" placeholder="" class="form-control " value="" name="lastname_conjoint_associe[]">
<input type="text" id="email_conjoint_associe" placeholder="" class="form-control " value="" name="email_conjoint_associe[]">
.... OTHER INPUTS BIENG VALIDATED ....
```

I need to mention that the inputs giving me the error are the listed above and they are not being validated.

the error is as follows:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68605222/15648920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs that their name contains `[]` at the end send an array to the server.
You may not pass an array to htmlspecialchars(), as it excepts string.